# error in using M block (in Xilinx system generator)?

Tags: matlab, simulink, xilinx

I wrote this code inside the M Blcok (one of Xilinx blockstes in Simulink):

```
function z= discorr(x,y)

t=zeros(12288,1);
i=zeros(12288,1);
k=zeros(12288,1);
i(4096:8191,1)=x(1:4096,2); %output of the image filter
t(4096:8191,1)=y(1:4096,2);   %output of the tamplate filter
i=i';
z=A(1:4096,1);
    for n=1:8191
k=zeros(12288,1);
k(n:n+4095,1)=t(4096:8191,1);
z(n,2)=i*k;

     end
end
```

*Its telling me:*

```
Error("discreatcorr.m"): Syntax error: Lexical error at line 15, column 0. Encountered:  after : "\';\r\nz=A(1:4096,1);\r\nfor n=1:8191\r\n k=zeros(12288,1);\r\n k(n:n+4095,1)=t(4096:8191,1);\r\n z(n,2)=i*k;\r\n end\r\nend\r\n"

Error("discreatcorr.m"): Syntax error: Lexical error at line 15, column 0. Encountered:  after : "\';\r\nz=A(1:4096,1);\r\nfor n=1:8191\r\n k=zeros(12288,1);\r\n k(n:n+4095,1)=t(4096:8191,1);\r\n z(n,2)=i*k;\r\n end\r\nend\r\n"
Error occurred during "Block Configuration".
```

**althogh there is nothing in line 15 in the code**

**it is giving an error at the end of the code**

Any Ideas??

Comment: I have a feeling that even if it works, that'll synthesise to a staggeringly large amount of logic...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your system misinterprets the `'` symbol as string symbol. Replacing the line `i=i';` by `i=transp(i);` should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
I changed it , and it says:
 transp is not assigned with a value before this point. A misspelling or a switch statement without otherwise statement may cause this error.
Error occurred during "Rate and Type Error Checking".